# @ngrx/store select - How to convert Observable<Array<StaffInterface>> to Array<StaffInterface>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

tying to get `Array<StaffInterface>` from a `Observable<Array<StaffInterface>>` in ngrx store.select which returns the `Observable<Array<StaffInterface>>` so that i can pass the `Array<StaffInterface>` to primeng datatable.

```
staffList: Array<StaffInterface>; 
this.staffList = store.select(staffList);
```

In the above assignment store.select returns `Observable<Array<StaffInterface>>`. I need to convert it to `Array<StaffInterface>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the async pipe in your template.

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Answer (score 1):

You should be `subscribing` to the value and then return the array as below

```
this.staffList = store.select(staffList)
                          .subscribe(staffList => staffList);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, i changed my code to store.select to get the Store `Observable` data to `staffList$: Observable` and used `async` pipe in the template as told by @Brendan.

No conversion was needed between types.

```
staffList$: Array<StaffInterface>; 
this.staffList$ = store.select(staffList);
```

in HTML template:

```
{{staffList$ | async}}
```